# Get sublist till the end with Apache Commons

Tags: java, list, apache-commons

I want to get the Sublist of a List *l* with up to *pagesize* Elements, i did this till now by this:

```
l.subList(first, (l.size() > first + pagesize) ? pagesize : l.size())
```

Is there in the Apache commons a convenient Method for this, to make my code more readable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need Apache Commons for this. It can be implemented like this:

```java
l.subList(first, Math.min(l.size(), first + pagesize));
```

To go even further, you can import `Math.min` statically and reduce some more clutter:

```java
import static java.lang.Math.min;

...

l.subList(first, min(l.size(), first + pagesize));
```

Answer (score 6):

Since Java 8 you can do it with stream

```
list.stream()
    .skip(first)
    .limit(pagesize)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If possible, I would even skip `collect()` part and work with stream directly. Not sure about efficiency of overall solution, but I find it much more readable.